# Execute NodeJS module with specific variables injected

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I have a module like below

```
'use strict';

var val = GlobalVariable.someMethod();

...
...

module.exports = myExportedClass;
```

I am calling it with `require('./myModule');`. But would like to know if `GlobalVariable` can be dynamically injected.

I have tried this method, though I know that this does not work :)

```
(function(GlobalVariable) {
    require('./myModule');
})(SomeOtherGlobalVariable);
```

So it did not, because module will execute in different scope. Is there any other way where I can pass my own version of GlobalVariable when using require.

Comment: Please explain more. It's difficult to understand what you really want to achieve here.

Comment: No, you cannot pass anything to `require` to inject it in a module scope. But you could simply export a function with parameters, which is then called with arguments.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, currently I am using in same way but I am finding it difficult (to maintain) with our existing code base.

Comment: @Bergi Any possibility of I am using requireJS?

Comment: @Exception The grammar of your previous comment is incorrect so it not clear what you mean. Do you mean to say that you *are* using RequireJS?? Or do you mean to ask whether it is possible to do it *if* you use RequireJS?

Comment: @Louis I agree that I did not frame my prev comment properly. Yes, that means if I am using RequireJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be injected. Do something like the following:

```
module.exports = function(injectedObject) {
  return {
    doSomething: function() {
      return injectedObject.something();
    }
  }  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass you variable as an argument when requiring it

```
yourvariable="value";
var file = require('./myModule')(yourvariable);
```

or can pass it separately, as file now contain function reference of module.exports

```
yourvariable="value";
var file = require('./myModule');
file(yourvariable)
```

your module will look like as:

```
   module.exports = function(yourVaraible) {

        yourVaraible.myfunction =  function() {

        };
      return yourvariable;
    };
```